# Successfully push the record into Firebase, but Google Chrome hangs while pushing the data

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, bower, angularfire

This is the controller file of my app. It adds the data perfectly, but when it reaches the then key word google chrome hangs but key parameter is also added to the data base. I can't figure out where the problem is.

```
 .controller('recordsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray) {

        $scope.records = $firebaseArray(rootRef);

        //show form
        $scope.showAddForm = function(){
            $scope.addFormShow = true;
        }

        // hide form
        $scope.hide = function(){
            $scope.addFormShow = false;
        }

        // submit contact
        $scope.addFormSubmit = function() {

            console.log("adding form...")
            // Assign values
            if ($scope.lname) { var lname = $scope.lname; } else { var lname = null; }
            if ($scope.mname) { var mname = $scope.mname; } else { var mname = null; }
            if ($scope.fname) { var fname = $scope.fname; } else { var fname = null; }
            if ($scope.email) { var email = $scope.email; } else { var email = null; }      if ($scope.conId) { var conId = $scope.conId; } else { var conId = null;}


            // Build Object
            $scope.records.$add({

                fname: fname,
                lname: lname,
                mname: mname,
                email: email,
                company: company,         
                conId: conId

            }).then(function(rootRef) {
                ***//this is not printed in the console but the key is assigned to the database***
                console.log("Assign root key");
                var id = rootRef.key();
                console.log("Added Record with ID: " + id);

                // clear Form
                clearFields();

                // Hide Form
                $scope.addFormShow = false;

                // send message to use
                $scope.msg = "Record Added";
            });
        }

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team ran into this issue when we updated to Firebase 3.7.x. I believe this is a known bug.

**Try downgrading to Firebase 3.6.x.**

Comment: i tried downgrading also, but the problem still persists..now the new problem has arised when i update the record...it doesnt save the updated record in to the database..can i share my github link with you..can u please look at my code.if thats not a problem for u